# Check a column DB in azure, with a value from a python script in local

Tags: python, azure, arduino, cloud

I have this problem, because I am measuring the temperature of my room with a serial arduino.
I also have a db of plants in azure, that could grow in x temperatures.

I want to check if the temerature on my room is okay for the plants i have on my db to grow, but i dont know how to send this temperature value to azure and check the temperature column.

Any advice?

Thanks

At the moment I thout about having two files, one in azure (i dont know how to upload it to azure) and one in my local pc

The one on the cloud:

```
from arduinodb_pc import *
import pyodbc
import time

server = '...'
database = '...'
username = '...'
password = '...'   
driver= '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'
conn =  pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER=tcp:'+server+';PORT=1433;DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
cursor = conn.cursor()

def db_check_temperature_cold(farenh):
    cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM my_plants WHERE minTinF >= {farenh};") # Send query and execute
    # row = [id, Name, ..., maxTinF]
    row = cursor.fetchone() # Move to the next row; 
    list_of_names = []
    while row:
        list_of_names.append(row)
        row = cursor.fetchone() # Move to the next row

    return list_of_names
    

def db_check_temperature_hot(farenh):
    cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM my_plants WHERE maxTinF <= {farenh};") # Send query and execute
    # row = [id, Name, ..., maxTinF]
    row = cursor.fetchone() # Move to the next row; 
    list_of_names = []
    while row:
        list_of_names.append(row)
        row = cursor.fetchone() # Move to the next row

    return list_of_names

currentTinF =0
currentTinC=0
text_currentT=0
while True:

    currentTinF, currentTinC, text_currentT = update_T()

    too_cold = db_check_temperature_cold(currentTinF)
    too_hot = db_check_temperature_hot(currentTinF)
    
    if (too_cold): arduino_write_cold(arduino)
    if (too_hot): arduino_write_hot(arduino)

    time.sleep(15) # but every 10 minutes
```

The code in my local pc:

```
import datetime
import time
from arduinodb_cloud import *
import serial

arduino = serial.Serial(port='COM3', baudrate=115200, timeout=.1)

def update_T():
    """
    Updates the label where the time and temperature are shown
    """
    return arduino_read_T(arduino, -1)
    

def arduino_read_T(arduino, unit):
    """ 
    In this function, the current temperature will be read from the aruino.

    :param arduino: HW it is going to use for checking the T
    :param unit: If the user prefers ºF or ºC

    :return: f, c: current temerature in farenheit and celisus
             txt_currentT: Text that will be shown on the gui
    """
    global fbefore
    global cbefore
    x = datetime.datetime.now()
    arduino.write(bytes("readT", 'utf-8'))
    time.sleep(0.05)
    value =  arduino.readline()
    try:
        value = str(value).lstrip("b'")
        value = str(value).rstrip("'")
        f, c = str(value).split(",")
    except:
        try:
            f = fbefore
            c = cbefore
        except: 
            f=65.3
            c=18.5
    fbefore=f
    cbefore=c
    if unit == 1: txt_currentT = (f"Today, {x.day}/{x.month}/{x.year} at {x.hour}:{x.minute}:{x.second} it's {f}ºF")
    elif unit == 0: txt_currentT = (f"Today, {x.day}/{x.month}/{x.year} at {x.hour}:{x.minute}:{x.second} it's {c}ºC")
    else: txt_currentT = ""
    return float(f), float(c), txt_currentT


def arduino_write_cold(arduino):
    arduino.write(bytes("cold", 'utf-8'))


def arduino_write_hot(arduino):
    arduino.write(bytes("hot", 'utf-8'))
```